# How to wirte a query for updating two tables at a time?

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

HI i have two tables in my database named...Requests and Balance tracker which has no relation....but i want to select data from two tables and binf it two grid...

```
               Requests   
          EmpID   |EmpRqsts|EmpDescription|ApproverID|ApprovedAmount|RequestPriority
           1      |asdfsb  |sadbfsbdf     |1         |
           2      |asbfd   |sjkfbsd       |1         |

          Balance Tracker
          EmpId|BalanceAmnt|LastUpdated|lastApprovedAmount
         | 1   |5000       |sdfbk      |
         | 2   |3000       |sjbfsh     |
```

now i want  to update based on the EmpID two tables at a time...when ever amount is approved it should be updates in request table column [ApprovedAmount] and with priority...
when [ApprovedAmount] is Updated [BalanceAmnt] Balance Tracker  of also should be Updated by adding the amount approved,[LastUpdated],[lastApprovedAmount] should be updated with date and time

can any one help me with the query please....

Comment: It sure looks like your two tables have a relation on the empID column.  Please clarify.  

Also what does "and binf it two grid" mean?

Comment: Please clarify your post as it has contrary statements: "Requests and Balance tracker which has no relation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Anil, here is an example of SQL Server 2008 code which would help you to get your goal acomplished:

```
DECLARE @Requests TABLE
(
    EmpId int 
    , EmpRqsts nvarchar(50)
    , EmpDescription nvarchar(250)
    , ApproverID int
    , ApprovedAmount money 
    , RequestPriority int 
)

DECLARE @BalanceTracker TABLE
(
    EmpId int 
    , BalanceAmnt money 
    , LastUpdated datetime
    , lastApprovedAmount money
)

-- Insert data for testing
INSERT INTO @Requests VALUES
(
    1
    , 'Something here'
    , 'Some descriptio here'
    , 1
    , 100
    , 1
)

INSERT INTO @Requests VALUES
(
    2
    , 'Something here 2 '
    , 'Some descriptio here 3'
    , 1
    , 215
    , 2
)


INSERT INTO @BalanceTracker VALUES
(
    1
    , 5000
    , GETDATE() - 3
    , 310
)

INSERT INTO @BalanceTracker VALUES
(
    2
    , 3000
    , (GETDATE() - 1)
    , 98
)

-- Declare local variables
DECLARE
    @NewAmount money
    , @NewPriority int
    , @SelectedEmpId int

-- Assing values for example
SELECT @NewAmount = 1000
    , @SelectedEmpId = 1
    , @NewPriority = 5

-- Get the tables values pre - updates
SELECT  *
FROM    @Requests

SELECT  *
FROM    @BalanceTracker


BEGIN TRY

    -- Update the record with new ApprovedAmount and Request Priority
    UPDATE  @Requests
    SET ApprovedAmount = @NewAmount
        , RequestPriority = @NewPriority
    WHERE   EmpId = @SelectedEmpId

    -- If no error found then update BalanceAmnt trable
    IF (@@ERROR = 0)
    BEGIN TRY
        UPDATE  @BalanceTracker
        SET BalanceAmnt = (BalanceAmnt + @NewAmount)
            , LastUpdated = GETDATE()
            , lastApprovedAmount = @NewAmount
        WHERE   EmpId = @SelectedEmpId
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT N'Error found updating @BalanceTracker table: ' + ISNULL(LTRIM(STR(ERROR_NUMBER())) , N'Unknown Error' )
        + N', Message: ' + ISNULL ( ERROR_MESSAGE() , N'No Message' )
    END CATCH
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT N'Error found updating @Requests table: ' + ISNULL(LTRIM(STR(ERROR_NUMBER())) , N'Unknown Error' )
        + N', Message: ' + ISNULL ( ERROR_MESSAGE() , N'No Message' )
END CATCH

-- Get the tables values post - updates
SELECT  *
FROM    @Requests

SELECT  *
FROM    @BalanceTracker
```

**Note 1**: @Table are Variable Tables handlded by SQL Server 2008. If you're using previous version you should be able to create Temporary Table (#Table).
**Note 2**: data data-types may vary depending upon the SQL version you're using.

Comment: @Anil, Ps: I'm blindely trusting on what you want to do without questions from design perspectives. My assumption is the EmpID is a FK linking records from Requests and BalanceTracker tables.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this type of thing with a trigger. This way whenever you do the first update, it will automatically do the other update you specify.

Comment: can u help me how to use a trigger...@jroyce